# Type exists in both System.Data.Common and System.Data.SqlClient

Tags: .net-8.0, stackexchange.exceptional

I have a ASP.NET Core web application (.NET 8) with only one dependency:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.1" />
```

I'm trying to add the Exceptional library:

```
<PackageReference Include="StackExchange.Exceptional.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.32" />
```

I have existing code referring to `System.Data.SqlDbType`, and after adding Exceptional I get the following build error:

> The type 'SqlDbType' exists in both 'System.Data.Common, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

How can I fix it?

Comment: It's not pretty, but an `extern alias` would work for this case!  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured just adding an explicit reference to the `System.Data.SqlClient` package solved the issue:

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.6" />
```